# MYSQL inserting data

Tags: php, head

i am facing problem during inserting data in mysql database.
the error is showed like this:
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1')' at line 1"

```
<?php


    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $fathername = $_POST['fathername'];
    $mothername = $_POST['Firstname'];
    $fatherjob = $_POST['fatherjob'];
    $motherjob = $_POST['motherjob'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $mobile1 = $_POST['mobile1'];
    $mobile2 = $_POST['mobile2'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $id=1;
    $roll=1;

    $sex = $_POST['sex'];
    $bloodgroup = $_POST['bloodgroup'];
    $class = $_POST['class'];
    $section = $_POST['section'];
    $day = $_POST['day'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $birthday=$day."-".$month."-".$year;


    $hostname_localhost ="localhost";
    $database_localhost ="school";
    $username_localhost ="root";
    $password_localhost ="";
    $localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
    or
    trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

    mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO student_info VALUES ('".$id."',".$firstname."','".$lastname."','".$sex."','".$bloodgroup."','".$fathername."','".$mothername ."','".$fatherjob."','".$motherjob."','".$address."','".$birthday."','".$phone."','".$mobile1."','".$mobile2."','".$class."','".$section."','".$roll."')";

     mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
     echo "updated  succesfully";

?>
```

BTW, i ahve 2 columns in my table named id and roll which should be generated automatically...in that case, is it the right sql ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way for your case is to use the query that mention the columns like below :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO student_info (id, firstname, ..... ) VALUES ('".$id."',".$firstname."','".$lastname."','".$sex."','".$bloodgroup."','".$fathername."','".$mothername ."','".$fatherjob."','".$motherjob."','".$address."','".$birthday."','".$phone."','".$mobile1."','".$mobile2."','".$class."','".$section."','".$roll."')";
```

Answer (score 1):

YES THERE IS A SYNTAX ERROR
THE RIGHT SYNTAX IS :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO (id,firstname) VALUES (1,'Oussaki')";
```

you have to specified the fields that you want to insert on it .. that all good luck

Answer (score -1):

You've made a mistake here

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO student_info VALUES ('".$id."',".$firstname."','".$lastname."','".$sex."','".$bloodgroup."','".$fathername."','".$mothername ."','".$fatherjob."','".$motherjob."','".$address."','".$birthday."','".$phone."','".$mobile1."','".$mobile2."','".$class."','".$section."','".$roll."')";
```

To insert data in MYSQL, you have to first confirm to which `column`  you want to insert and which value.
So before declaring `VALUES`, you have first to specify the column to which you want to store `$id $firstname`.
The same applies to others.

Also, you don't need a "dot" before and after `$id` and others.
I hope your database have columns like `id firstname` and so on.

**Correct code for example**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO student_info (id,firstname) VALUES ('$id',$firstname');
```